# Creating an array of JSON objects in JavaScript on a Razor page from custom viewmodel in MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to populate the array in my script (it's going to be used for charting with D3.JS later on). According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23781320/1525840), I'm supposed to use the syntax below. However, it doesn't work, bacause I get the error on the pushy line saying *Uncaught ReferenceError: WebSite is not defined*, where *WebSite* is the name of the namespace of the data (I'm guessing that, as it's the name of my project).

```
<script>
  var data = new Array();
  @foreach (var piece in @Model.DataPieces)
  {
    @:data.push(@piece);
  }
</script>
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the data type of *piece*, because the following change makes it work (at least not producing a bunch of errors). I'm picking out the individual fields from *piece* object and push those into the array, as a new object.

```
<script>
  var data = new Array();
  @foreach (var piece in @Model.DataPieces)
  {
    @:data.push({'cat': '@piece.Category', 'key': '@piece.Key', 'val': '@piece.Value'});
  }
</script>
```

It's inconvenient, prone to mistakes and requires a refactoring of the assignment each time the model changes. How can I avoid this approach and be able to automagically create JSON objects upon assignment, as shown in the first sample?

The viewmodel for the Razor page is declared as folows.

```
namespace WebSite.Models
{
  public class DrillDataViewModel
  {
    public List<DataPiece> DataPieces { get; set; }

    public class DataPiece
    {
      public string Category { get; set; }
      public string Key { get; set; }
      public int Value { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why anyone would do it this way and not simply pass whole array to javascript variable as json output. Javascript compiler then sees the printed json as a javascript array that is completely ready for consumption

Comment: @charlietfl Might be several reasons. Ignorance being the most likely, perhaps. How would you suggest to approach it? I'm there with my array from *@Model* - how do I pass it into the JavaScript method, exactly? We're talking about the *onload* right? Please elaborate.

Comment: No... not onload. Rather than create your razor loop, serialize your array to json and print it   `var data = <% serialized_json_output %>` . I don't know dot Net syntax for this. Now when browser gets it is ready to be used immediately

Comment: My suggestion matches # 6 in this post. https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/02/05/passing-net-server-side-data-to-javascript. For long array avoids new line in page source for each and every element in your array

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah, I'm trying it out too. However, serializing gives me a bunch of *&quot;* elements, like this: *"[{&quot;Category&quot;:&quot;Name 7&quot;,&quot;Key&quot;:&quot;Key 5&quot;,&quot;Value&quot;:35}* which creates a lot of space waste...

Comment: That's not valid either...should be literal quotes. I guess I am spoiled working in php and node.js where all this is done with a single encoding statement.

Comment: @charlietfl Hehe, right. I'll see if I can work it out on .NET side. But just to be clear - it's supposed to be single quotes around the names of the fields in JSON, right? Like this: *[{'Category':'Name 7','Key':'Key 5',';Value':35}]*.

Comment: Does this work `var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.DataPieces))`;?

Comment: JSON itself is supposed to be double quotes and serializer will escape any quotes within the string values. Javascript doesn't care as long as they match. What you output as JSON just to print will we read by js compiler as literal array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass this from Razor page to JavaScript.

```
@Html.Raw(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.DataPieces)
  .Replace("{\"", "{")
  .Replace(",\"", ",")
  .Replace("\":", ":"))
```

The replaces serve to get rid of the invalid characters produced by default in the converter without you needing to play with streams or applying other libraries. Ugly but working.

Sometimes, I also add one more replace: *.Replace("\"","'")* to get a more JS like look. The outer method is needed so you don't get problems with *&* in the *"e;*.

This is a hand-on solution so if anybody knows a better way, I'd love to get some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The line `@:data.push(@piece);` will be written to the output HTML as

```
data.push(<the result of calling ToString() on @piece>);
```

You need to replace `@piece` with something that will be evaluated to the JSON you want. This should work:

```
@:data.push(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(piece)));
```

Or you can just output the whole array at once:

```
var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DataPieces));
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. When I use your suggestion (second one), I get *Unterminated template literal* and checking the page, I see that *data* got the value of *System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebSite.Models.DrillDataViewModel+DataPiece]* and not the actual values. It feels like if we're close now. Suggestions?

Comment: @KonradViltersten, you got that error because I left the `Json.Encode` part out. Sorry, I've edited my answer and it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
    `var yourJavascriptArray=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(YouModel));`