# The name 'ui' does not exist in the current context

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, razor, jquery-ui-slider

The name 'ui' does not exist in the current context

```
@sliderName=my Array


    $(function () {
        $("#@sliderName").slider({
           range: true,
           min: 1,
           max: 10,
           values: [@minValue, @maxValue],
           slide: function (event, ui) {
               var minnewValue=ui.values[0];
               var k=@sliderName[ui.values[0]];

               $("#@sliderNamePrice").val(k + " - " +@sliderName[ui.values[0]]);
           }
       });

    });
```

I try many thing but evry time thows an error like **The name 'ui' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: Where are you calling your slide function from?

Comment: If this is the jQueryUI slider then tag your question with the relevant tag. Or point us in the direction of the plugin you are actually using.

Comment: Whats plugin you are used?

Comment: Are you sure your variable name `@sliderName` is correct? It's not invalid?

Comment: You can see this jsfiddle and it work fine! [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MoHSenMHS/39y9jLoh/2/)

Comment: JavaScript identifiers cannot start with an `@` symbol: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers.

Comment: @mhs Please refer my all code in :[link]https://jsfiddle.net/39y9jLoh/7/

Comment: Your code has many syntax error, can you correct them?

Comment: @MSH He's using Razor syntax. He failed to mention the error is occurring during .NET compilation.

Comment: Hi all I can't correct it b'coze it's in my razor code any it's very long.,So I can't upload it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the Razor view engine, and you are attempting to access client-side variables from server-side code. You need to create a client-side variable to store your array and use that in the `slide` callback.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781034/razor-mvc-populating-javascript-array-with-model-array) on how to do so.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your problem is connected to your use of the word "event" for the name of a function parameter. Try changing it.

Comment: It's not, but it's a global variable in IE.

Comment: I try but Not helpfull