# fullcalendar scheduler resources using items from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying to make a website using Fullcalendar scheduler plugin and want to be able to use the items from my Model to fill in the "Resources".

the resources-function looks like this:

```
resources: [
        { id: 'room01', title: 'Room 1' },
        { id: 'room02', title: 'Room 2' },
        ],
```

But I want to be able to do something like this:

```
resources: [
@foreach (var item in model) 
{
{ id: item.id, title: item.firstname };
}
        ],
```

However its not working and I cant really understand why.
I tried using parenthesis to make it look the same like this:

```
"{ id: '" + item.id + ", title: '"+  item.firstname + " }"
```

but its not working. 
I am very new to coding and never used advanced commands like this before.
Please advice how I could solve this.

Comment: You can use `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` to convert your model to a JavaScript array, so you should have a view model containing a `IEnumerable<T> resources` property where `T` contains properties `string id` and `string title`

Comment: Refer also [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781034/razor-mvc-populating-javascript-array-with-model-array) for some other options

Comment: Allright, thanks. I'll look into that.