# ForEach statement for values in an autocomplete search

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here, but I am trying to add in the author names (or au_fname) from an author. I want to use the author's name in an autocomplete search. So far this is what I have.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(function () {            
            var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
    var stra = [];
    model.forEach(function (element) {
            stra.push(element.au_fname);
        });
    $("#id").autocomplete({
            source: stra           
    });
});       
</script>
```

I'm not sure how I am supposed to link the element to be able to access au_fname. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Razor MVC Populating Javascript array with Model Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781034/razor-mvc-populating-javascript-array-with-model-array)

Comment: stra is an array so what this is doing is looping through the Serialized Modal and adding each name(au_fname ) to an array

Comment: What type is `Model` ?

Comment: This should work as long as Model is a collection type of objects with an `au_fname` property. What is happening now ?

Comment: Well that problem is the model is not linked to the author model and Im not sure how to get it to bind to that