# How do you access a Dictionary<int, string> in an external Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a select element in my razor view and I want to populate its options using code in an external Javascript file.  The option data consists of a Dictionary which is available to my controller class.  How can I access that dictionary in the JS file, via my view model?

Comment: Are you using the razor views?

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is populating a drop down menu, like most people, then you don't have to worry about that. You can simply build the options right from C# in your Razor view.

[Populating a razor dropdownlist from a List<object> in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382311/populating-a-razor-dropdownlist-from-a-listobject-in-mvc)

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedUserRoleId)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedUserRoleId, Model.UserRoles)
```

I that's not your use case, then you can populate your JS array in a slightly different manner.

[Razor MVC Populating Javascript array with Model Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781034/razor-mvc-populating-javascript-array-with-model-array)

```
var myArray = [];

@foreach (var d in Model.data)
{
    @:myArray.push("@d");  // for basic data
    //  or
    @:myArray.push(ClassMember1: "@d.ClassMember1", ClassMember2: "@d.ClassMember2"); // for objects
}
```