# How (in Razor) to transfer data from c # array to script (JS) array?

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, razor

I have this:

```
<script>var questions = ['A', 'B', 'C'];</script>
```

And I want something like from that to this:

```
<script>var questions = [@foreach (var word in Word) { word.abc; } ]</script>
```

That mistake because **I don't know how using '' in Razor**

Comment: Pls take a look. Similar question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781034/razor-mvc-populating-javascript-array-with-model-array)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using razor, you can use this.

```
<script>
    @{ //example
        var Word = new string[]{ "A", "B", "C" };
    }

    var questions = [@Html.Raw($"'{string.Join("','", Word)}'")];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<text>` block to transfer raw strings to js.

```
<script>
var questions = [];
@foreach (var word in Word) { 
    <text>
  questions.push('@word.abc');
    </text>
} 
</script>
```